# LASSO regression for categorical variables

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data, lasso, glmnet

Suppose there are several categorical variables included in the LASSO regression.

For a categorical variable with more than two factors, it is mandatory to create a dummy table.

For example, the categorical variable is vaccination status (Vacc_Stat), in which there are three categories,i.e., 1 = not vaccinated, 2 = partially vaccinated, and 3 = fully vaccinated.

Using the model. matrix function for the vaccination status variable will yield two dummy columns because the value 1= not vaccinated is the reference.

If the final result of the LASSO regression coefficient is as follows

Vacc_Stat1            .
Vacc_Stat2            .
Vacc_Stat3           -4.208877e-01

Do we use the Vacc_Stat3 only, or we used the Vacc_Stat variable as a whole?

I am planning to do a LASSO regression followed by a logistic regression of the remaining variables selected through LASSO regression.

Thank you in advance.

I am expecting that if one of the dummy variables is included in the LASSO regression, then we used the original categorical variable as a whole.

The following is the minimal reproducible dataset

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.34, 0.49, 38, 0.58, 0.2, 0.49, 0.65, 
40.57, 2.08, 49.52, 50.77, 38.04, 76.55, 55.95, 53.23, 38.04, 
99.72, 80.04, 92.41, 47, 66, 70, 52, 36, 39, 67, 42, 23, 66, 
37.109375, 31.22945431, 26.2345679, 20.76124567, 35.3798127, 
26.44628099, 23.87511478, 24.8015873, 21.49959688, 22.47120876, 
110, 159, 127, 100, 120, 115, 100, 112, 130, 119, 72, 78, 80, 
72, 80, 73, 76, 75, 80, 78, 84, 86, 88, 103, 90, 91, 90, 82, 
88, 105, 36, 37, 36.5, 36, 38, 38, 36, 36.4, 37, 36, 20, 40, 
24, 20, 22, 24, 18, 20, 22, 20, 90, 99, 98, 99, 96, 90, 98, 99, 
99, 90, 7, 5, 0, 2, 7, 10, 3, 3, 2, 2, 11.7, 13.8, 13, 10.9, 
11.6, 14.5, 15, 16.2, 12.3, 14.2, 3.9, 4.2, 3.6, 4.7, 4, 3.2, 
4.4, 5.1, 3, 3.78, 15.7, 28.8, 6, 7.8, 37.6, 13.9, 26.6, 27.2, 
33, 23, 138, 139, 121, 135, 139, 132, 133, 138, 137, 128, 75, 
64.5, 87.4, 88.9, 47.1, 78, 61.8, 62.52, 56.3, 63.2, 753, 305, 
250, 267, 315, 207, 285, 293, 366, 307, 8.7, 8.1, 11.2, 75.9, 
13.7, 10.03, 42.2, 10, 9, 10.6, 11.07, 6.8, 1.18, 23.18, 4.33, 
5.25, 8.73, 7.44, 8.01, 10.37), dim = c(10L, 76L), dimnames = 
list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), 
c("TEST.Year2",                                                                    
"TEST.Year3", "TEST.Gender2", "TEST.Vacc_Stat1", 
"TEST.Vacc_Stat2",                                                              
"TEST.Vacc_Stat3", "TEST.Risk_AI2", "TEST.Risk_Obesity2", 
"TEST.Risk_Smoking2",                                                                  
"TEST.Risk_HT2", "TEST.Risk_DM2", "TEST.Risk_Asthma2", 
"TEST.Risk_CHD2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Risk_CVD2", "TEST.Risk_COPD2", "TEST.Risk_TBC2", 
"TEST.Risk_CKD2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Risk_CLD2", "TEST.Risk_Brain2", "TEST.Risk_HIV2", 
"TEST.Risk_Cancer2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Symptom_Fever2", "TEST.Symptom_Cough2", 
"TEST.Symptom_Sore_Throat2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Symptom_Rinnorrhea2", "TEST.Symptom_Anosmia2", 
"TEST.Symptom_Myalgia2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Symptom_Headache2", "TEST.Symptom_Malaise2", 
"TEST.Symptom_Anorexia2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Symptom_Diarrhea2", "TEST.Symptom_Nausea2", 
"TEST.Symptom_Vomitting2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Symptom_Abd_Pain2", "TEST.Symptom_Dyspneu2", 
"TEST.Symptom_Chest_Pain2", 
                                                                  
"TEST.Symptom_LOC2", "TEST.Lab_RT_PCR2", "TEST.CXR_Proj2", 
"TEST.CXR_Proj3",                                                                   
"TEST.CXR_Pneumonia1", "TEST.CXR_Pneumonia2", 
"TEST.CXR_Effusion2",                                                                   
"TEST.Co_Septic2", "TEST.Co_Septic_Shock2", "TEST.Co_ARDS2",                                                                    
"TEST.Co_Sx_Infection2", "TEST.Severity_Adm2", 
"TEST.Severity_Adm3",                                                                      
"TEST.Severity_Adm4", "TEST.Severity_Adm_Cat_12", 
"TEST.Severity_Adm_Cat_22",                                                                      
"TEST.Severity_Adm_Cat_32", "TEST.Severity_Worst2", 
"TEST.Severity_Worst3",                                                                  
"TEST.Severity_Worst4", "TEST.Progression2", "TEST.CXR_ALA_Num",                                                                       
"TEST.CXR_Prob_Num", "TEST.Age", "TEST.BMI", "TEST.Vital_SBP",                                                                      
"TEST.Vital_DBP", "TEST.Vital_PR", "TEST.Vital_Temp", 
"TEST.Vital_RR",                                                                   
"TEST.Vital_SpO2", "TEST.Symptom_Onset", "TEST.Lab_Hb", 
"TEST.Lab_K",                                                                       
"TEST.Lab_Lim", "TEST.Lab_Na", "TEST.Lab_Neu", "TEST.Lab_Tr",                                                                        
"TEST.Lab_Ur", "TEST.Lab_WBC")))
```

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: The R package `glmnet` can do logit-lasso regressions, which likely makes more sense than the proposed two-step approach.